# Use parts of variable to modify line in text file

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
....
....
....
MY_TAG=Release_X_Y
....
....
```

The fourth line always looks like this and contains numbers. E.g. Release_1_1

The value I will have is an argument passed by a user which will look like this:

```
1_2_3
```

Where 1, 2, 3 will always be seperated by underscores but will be changing numbers.

I need to take those first two numbers i.e. 1 and 2 and use them to replace the line MY_TAG in my text file. Is it possible to do this with sed or awk?

**To summarise:**

Pre-existing file

```
....
MY_TAG=Release_1_2  <---Line 4
....
```

User passes argument to my script and its stored as a variable:

```
User arg = 4_9_2
```

I want to modify the file mentioned above to be:

```
....
MY_TAG=Release_4_9
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
RELEASE=${1%_*}  # Trim the last _X from the release number
sed -e "s/^MY_TAG=Release_[0-9_]*/MY_TAG=Release_$RELEASE/" -i file_path
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I had to modify it slightly because the version of sed I have available doesn't support -i. Doing the job nicely, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try this one-liner:

```
 awk -v arg="4_9_2" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="=";sub(/_[^_]*$/,"",arg)}NR==4{$2="Release_"arg}7' file
```

the `arg="4_9_2"` could be `arg="$var"`, which `$var` is a shall variable, passed in by user input.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in awk, but IMHO sed is a better match here.

Step one is to isolate the line you operate on.  This can indeed be done by line number (sed address `4`).  Or you might want to use something more robust in case the input file format is likely to evolve, e.g. a regex.

There you want to replace "Release_1_2" with "Release_4_9".  A regex substitution is perfect for the job: `s/Release_.*/Release_4_9/`.

A full working command should then be: `sed -e "4 s/Release_.*/Release_4_9/"`.  Supposing your target release number is in shell variable RELEASE, you'd interpolate it this way: `sed -e "4 s/Release_.*/Release_$RELEASE/"`.

This invocation is a filter: it takes your file on standard input (or as a command-line argument) and prints the result.  To have it modify the file in-place, with recent GNU versions of sed, use the `-i` option:

```
RELEASE=4_9
sed -e "4 s/Release_.*/Release_$RELEASE/" -i file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
ARG=$2
[[ -e $FILE && $ARG =~ ^[^_]+_[^_]+ ]] && sed -i "/^MY_TAG=/{ s|^\(MY_TAG=[^_]*\).*|\1_${BASH_REMATCH[0]}|; }" "$FILE"
```

Example:

```
bash script.sh file 1_4_5
```

Output:

```
...
...
...
MY_TAG=Release_1_4
...
...
...
```